# Freeing up space/swap partition

Tags: swap

Ok, so I have 8gb ram on my machine (aluminum MacBook 2008, dual boot). When I installed Ubuntu, it created a swap partition nearly 9gb in size. I don't know but it seems a bit excessive.  Is it safe to resize the swap partition and add it to boot partition?

Comment: 9G swap is fine. Leave it alone. Even if you HAD to resize, you'd only gain a tiny amount to add to your boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is completely safe to resize your swap and boot partitions (As long as you don't make the boot partition too small.)

A general rule of thumb is that your swap partition should be the same size as the amount of RAM you have in your computer. (In your case, 8000mb)

As a matter of fact, you can technically delete your swap partition altogether. Although this is something I would heavily recommend you **not** do, it would not cause any significant damage to your system.

Just remember, you will have to resize your partitions from a Live environment, using a partitioning tool such as GParted. If the live environment automatically mounts your swap partition and starts using it, remember to unmount it. In Gparted, you would right-click the swap partition and select "swapoff."

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MJ6r.png)